# Which document generator is used by peerjs

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation

This question may not be a programming question but it is what every programmer wants, i.e. clear good documentation of it's code, I know there are many document generator tools available:

http://www.lsauer.com/2013/05/javascript-documentation-generator.html

but I am looking for a document generator which has good UI like peerjs see the link http://peerjs.com/docs/#start

Can anyone tell me which document generator peerjs is using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PeerJS uses referencejs for their docs: https://github.com/michelle/reference ( found that here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/peerjs/5VgPtZCWYTA )

Comment: Thanks for answering , but as it says it is specific for peerjs can anyone suggest any generic lib, further to dump all data in json format is a pain.

Comment: You're welcome. No sorry - I don't have any recommendations for you, Maybe this one though: https://github.com/petebacondarwin/dgeni-example - used by AngularJS team.